KDE Plasma application launcher menu editing
Using kmenuedit on a KDE-Plasma 6.2.4 - KDE-FrameWorks 6.9.0 DeskTop in openSUSE Tumbleweed:
I have added a sub-menu entry (QT Tools) under the menu entry Development and cut from the Development entry all QT Applications and pasted in the QT Tools sub-menu of Development.
After saving, I select the application launcher surfing to the Development entry to find nothing has been updated or changed, not even the new sub-menu QT Tools is reflected. What am I doing so wrong here?
I've obviously missed the boat for I'm feeling wet behind my ears and more than slightly embarrassed.

Have you restart the plasma shell and have you try to update-desktop-database ?

restart the plasma https://discuss.kde.org/t/how-to-restart-plasma-panel/15490

https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/1csjrkn/how_to_completely_restart_kde_including_all/
